# Cant select field name in MySQL that contains an asterisk

Tags: mysql, database

I need to make reference to a field that contains an asterisk as identifier but it can't be recognized by MySQL in a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER new_data_inserted AFTER INSERT on table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2(special*) SELECT NEW.special*;
END;
```

I tried by escaping the * with :

```
INSERT INTO table2(special\*) SELECT NEW.special\*;
```

And also:

```
INSERT INTO table2('special*') SELECT 'NEW.special*';
```

but in both cases MySQL throws an Error Code: 1064

Any solution? it's important to note that field name **musn't** be renamed (client requirements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the column name in backticks like so:

```
`special*`
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1af5a)